# Mac: truly detach process from Terminal.app

Tags: bash, terminal.app

On Mac OS 10.6.6, I want to make a bash alias or function that will run Google Chrome. Launching Chrome is easy: "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome". The problem is how to detach the Chrome process tree from Terminal.app so that when I close the terminal window, it doesn't kill Chrome. I have tried all of the following, to no avail:

```
"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" &

nohup "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"

"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" &
disown

screen "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"

screen "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" &
```

Any suggestions for how to truly detach the Chrome process tree from Terminal.app? Alternatively, is there another way to make a command-line shortcut to launch and detach Chrome?

---

EDIT:
Note that the answers to this question apply equally well for launching other applications besides just Chrome.

Comment: Please edit your question to apply to all applications. We don't need a copy of this topic for every Mac application under the sun.

Comment: Not what I meant. Since we keep track of the history of each post, there's no reason to let old content survive. I'd suggest you edit the title to be more generic ("Launch Mac application detached from Terminal" or something like that) and only use Chrome as an example. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Daniel Feel free to make whatever edits you want. I see you have enough rep and are quite knowledgeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> `open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"`

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Weirdly, if you use the full path to the executable, it spawns a new terminal window: open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" .  Any idea why?

Comment: @Jon `open` uses Launch Services to determine what application to open a file with. If you do it like William suggests, it opens the Mac application bundle, but you start the unix binary itself, which gets a window for console output (`stdout`). `open` returns immediately, so there's not a lot of other options. You can also use `open -a "Google Chrome"` to let Launch Services determine which registered copy of Google Chrome to start.

Comment: @Daniel Beck Apparently this also works: open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"

Comment: @Jon Sure, but what's the point? Since it's an application, it'll get started with or without the argument `-a`. The semantics are slightly different (*open the file `...` using the default application for that type*, and *open the application `...`*), but the result is the same.

Comment: @Daniel Try it. Without the -a launches a new terminal window, which is annoying. With the -a does not, so I would prefer the latter.

Comment: @Jon Interesting. Do you want that window? It's not exactly an improvement on your situation before, it still uses a Terminal windows it's dependent on. Though by specifying the full path to the actual binary, you're depending on that to never change. I suggest doing what William did when you want to launch a specific copy of Chrome, and doing what I suggested in the first comment when you just want to launch the Chrome registered with Launch Services.

Answer (score 1):

```
open -a "Google Chrome"
```

This will open Chrome without regard to where it is installed, which may be desirable over a hardcoded path.

Also note that using `open` differs from running the executable directly in that it will not launch a *second* copy of Chrome. This is correct Mac behavior; running the executable directly **should not be done** unless you have a special need such as passing command-line arguments (which a proper Mac application should never need in normal circumstances).

Comment: `open -na "Google Chrome"` does open a second instance. `open -a "Google Chrome" --args "someArg"` passes arguments.

Comment: Interesting. `--args` is apparently new in 10.6, but `-n` is new to me as well. Evidently I haven't read the man page for `open` in a while.